# swift: App Delegate View controller access?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and am trying to build my first app, I would like some help with getting the variable for accessing app delegate from the ViewController

I tried to use the code

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
```

However, it is not recognising sharedApplication() as a function and I get an error saying "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIApplications'. "

Comment: Have you looked at the reference documentation for `UIApplication`?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3 this is `UIApplication.shared.delegate`

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't annotate the type.
2. `appDel` is supposed to be a constant.
3. You have to forced downcast the type (it's safe, the application delegate class is required).
4. As mentioned in the comments the signature is wrong. An easy way to figure out the syntax is to <kbd>⌘-click</kbd> on the symbol (`UIApplication`) and look up the declaration in the header file.

---

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```